# ios7 change data in tab1 from tab2

Tags: ios7, xcode6

I've created a test app to debug this issue so it simply has 2 views, tabs and controllers using storyboard layout in xcode6.

I have a label on tab 1 view and when I hit tab 2, I'd like to change it, e.g. it reads 'foo' now and when I tab back it will say 'bar'.

**ViewController.h**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *tab1Label;

@end
```

**ViewController2.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
...
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ViewController *myVC = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
NSLog(@"%@", myVC.tab1Label.text);
myVC>tab1Label.text = @"bar";
}
```

It could simply be that I'm calling the other view controller in the wrong way but I'm not sure the right way. The Log output is null when picking up the current text of the label.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = self.tabBarController;
ViewController *myVC = (ViewController *) tabBarController.viewControllers[0];  // 0 = 1st VC
```

Was the missing link (courtesy of @rcasey on raywenderlich.com)